# Existence of improper integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I want to show that the improper integral $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x)}dx$$ exists. In order to do that, I split the integral into  $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x)}dx + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x)}dx$, so that I can compute a value for $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x)}dx$, which proves the existence for that part.

For the other part, is it sufficient to show that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x)}dx < \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx$ knowing that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx$ exists, to say that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x)}dx$ exist and therefore the whole improper integral exists? Thanks for an answer in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin x$ may be negative in $[1,\infty)$, so $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(1+x)}\,dx < \int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,dx$ is not quite correct. What you can say, by the squeeze theorem, is that
$$\left|\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(1+x)}\,dx\right|\le\int_1^\infty\frac1{x(1+x)}\,dx\le\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,dx$$
and since the last integral converges, so does the leftmost integral without the absolute value signs.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. When trying to get the integral for $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x)}dx$ I just noticed that I'd have to work with approximation. Now I'm asking myself, does your statement remain true for the whole integral $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x)}dx$$ ? That would make the proof a lot easier.

Comment: @M.P. No you can't; $\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^2}$ blows up at $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that. Do you have any other idea of how to prove existence for the first part? Or do I have to go the long route?

Comment: @M.P. You could expand the numerator into the Maclaurin series of $\sin x$, then show that the sum of all parts converges.

Comment: @M.P. Ah! A better idea for the $(0,1]$ bit is in d'Aurizio's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathcal{L}(\sin x)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x(x+1)}\right)=1-e^{-s}$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x(x+1)}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{(s^2+1)e^s} $$
where the last integral is clearly positive, but bounded by
$$\sqrt{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{(s^2+1)^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ds}{e^{2s}}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$$
by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. $\frac{\pi}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$ is a fairly sharp approximation of the actual value of the integral; a crude and much more elementary bound can be obtained by integrating $0\leq \frac{\sin x}{x(x+1)} \leq \frac{1}{x+1}$ over $(0,1]$ and $\frac{|\sin x|}{x(x+1)}\leq\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ over $[1,+\infty)$.