# Convergence Problem of Improper Integrals

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

In this post (c.f. [Existence of improper integral.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243016/existence-of-improper-integral)), in Parcly Taxel's Answer, he concluded that the improper integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(1+x)}\,dx$ converges by the estimate

$$\left|\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(1+x)}\,dx\right|\le\int_1^\infty\frac1{x(1+x)}\,dx\le\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,dx.$$

I don't really understand why the boundedness of $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(1+x)}\,dx$ is sufficient to ensure the convergence of it, because I think it may oscillate.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is really happening is an analogue of *absolutely convergent series*. If a series is absolutely convergent, then the original series is convergent. One proves this by showing that if the series is absolutely convergent, then the originial series satifies a *Cauchy condition*.

In a similar fashion, if an improper integral is *absolutely convergent*, then the original improper integral is convergent. So, what do we mean by an absolutely convergent improper integral? We say that the improper integral $\int_a^{\to b}f(x)\,dx$ converges absolutely if
$$
  \int_a^{\to b}|f(x)|\,dx
$$
converges. (What "$\to b$" means is simply "take the limit $\lim_{t\to b}\int_a^tf(x)\,dx$".)

Now, to prove that if an improper integral is absolutely convergent then it is convergent we prove it as if we were dealing with series: we prove that the original improper integral, which is really a limit, satisfies a *Cauchy condition*. The difference is that this Cauchy condition is for limits and not just limits of sequences. (Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419909/cauchy-condition-for-functions)
can help clarifying what I mean by Cauchy condition for a limit.)

Going back to your problem, what Taxel really did was proving that the improper integral is absolutely convergent:
$$
  \int_1^\infty \left|\frac{\sin x}{x(1+x)}\right|\,dx\leq
  \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(1+x)}\,dx \leq\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx
  ,
$$
and so, the original improper integral converges!

Comment: I was aware of the limits were taken in terms of nets rather than of sequences, but I didn't know how to deal with it before. Thanks for introducing the notion of Cauchy condition to me, which really helps me out with the convergence question.

Comment: Don't worry, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If it oscillates it helps the convergence. When one limit becomes $\infty$ the integral is improper, for it to be convergent  the integrand near $x \sim infty$ must fall faster than $\frac{1}{|x|}$ when $x\pm \infty.$  This is so because
$$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\beta} < \infty, ~ if~\beta>1.$$
You may check that $$I_1=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{1.01}} =\infty$$ but
$$I_2=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{0.99}}$$ is finite.

Here in your case $\beta=2$, so your integral is improper but convergent.

Comment: I know the basic fact about convergence or divergence of $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^p}$ for all $p>0$, which doesn't help in my question though. @EBO 's answer makes more sense to me. Anyway thanks for your answer. :)